# Class not found in xml created in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying CardsUI, I have following code: Including NowActivity Code

NowActivity.java where I define the behaviour

```
    package com.example.rushdesktop.testingweather;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class NowActivity extends LinearLayout implements OnGlobalLayoutListener {

    public NowActivity(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    { super(context, attrs); initLayoutObserver(); }

    public NowActivity(Context context)
    { super(context); initLayoutObserver(); }

    private void initLayoutObserver()
    { // force vertical orientation and add observer
    setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this); }

    @Override public void onGlobalLayout()
    {
        getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        final int heightPx =getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        boolean inversed = false;
        final int childCount = getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            int[] location = new int[2];
            child.getLocationOnScreen(location);
            if (location[1] > heightPx) { break; }

            if (!inversed) {
                child.startAnimation( AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_up_left));
            }
            else {
                child.startAnimation( AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_up_right));
            }

            inversed = !inversed;
        }
    }
```

I use it in my main activity xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fillViewport="true">

<com.example.rushdesktop.testingweather.NowActivity android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#e3e3e3" android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/txtView" style="@style/nowCardStyle" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hello_world" tools:context=".MyActivity" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/txtView1" style="@style/nowCardStyle" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hello_world" tools:context=".MyActivity" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/txtView2" style="@style/nowCardStyle" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hello_world" tools:context=".MyActivity" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/txtView3" style="@style/nowCardStyle" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hello_world" tools:context=".MyActivity" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/txtView4" style="@style/nowCardStyle" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hello_world" tools:context=".MyActivity" />

</com.example.rushdesktop.testingweather.NowActivity>

</ScrollView>
```

As in the code I use the Java class in my main activity xml. But when I build my code I get error showing the class was not found in the XML. Please help me with the issue.

Here is the link to my full android studio code:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6P-8t-14MK-dEZ0bHJqRzBvUmVaSW5ySTR3My1mN0U1OThV/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance.

Comment: give us your code for `NowActivity`

Comment: Code for NowActivity shared

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the only child of the scroll layout (com.example.rushdesktop.testingweather.NowActivity) inherits some sort of layout (i.e. RelativeLayout, FrameLayout...) does it?

Comment: I have shared my NowActivity Code. Please advice

Comment: as stated by @hypd09 thats an Activity.. the xml layout needs a view.  this library you are using somewhere probably has a class that extends View (NOT activity)  that is the class you want to reference in your xml

Comment: Try, in the xml, to remove the context tags for the TextViews. It may not can find that class.

Comment: Removing the context didnt work. I have shared my View code now. NowActivity.java is not an activity just the naming I have done mistake

Comment: Do you mind sharing the stack trace of when the exception is thrown?

Comment: Joshua I have shared the full code. Can you please try it out and help me?

Comment: Check this out: I think i fixed that problem, just incase i didn't, try importing it as a new project... [here's the project](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B71g6yvvLo_7Z0JGV0ttRU9QQ0E&usp=sharing)

Comment: In Which files you have made the changes. Sorry, cant figure it out. Please help.

Comment: I actually just moved the locations mainly, the actual source code was in the wrong package, so it couldn't find it, also there was a menu xml file that had an error in it. so just import it into the IDE as a new project and see if it fixed the error.

Comment: The difference in the structure is due to ide we r using....i guess you r using eclipse whereas i am using Android Studio....Its still not working in android studio

Comment: Okay, sorry I couldn't help, however, one last thing, in the menu xml files try removing any of the lines where it says "showAsAction" then build and try to run it might work. This worked for me before when I had this problem...

Answer (score 0):

in your xml layout you need to use the View, not the activity.. the activity will set the layout it uses via setContentView(R.layout.[your layout])

in your xml layout, if you switch to graphical editor view you should be able to see the view you want listen in the custom & library views tab (in eclipse), providing you have included the library in the project build

Comment: I have shared my NowActivity Code. Please advice

Comment: please see http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html  in your case you won't have to create a custom view as the library probably already has created one.. but this should clear up what you are doing wrong..

Comment: Thanks erik. I have already read the article you have shared. I am trying things since last 2 days. I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: do you get that in your xml above you are trying to place an activity in your layout as a view, and why that is backwards?>

Comment: Hey erik, can you examine my full code. I have shared the link.

Comment: can you post the actual log error for Class not found

Comment: Hey erik, m getting error saying Rendering problem class not found in android studio. May be there is some structurual issue of files and folders. But cant figure it out.

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to get back to you.. i am on vacation.. but i will be honest, i don't use android studio and am still using eclipse, can you post the exact error and maybe i can help?  what class is not found?